# Shell Method vs Washer Method at line y=2

Tags: calculus, volume

I was teaching today about the Washer Method vs the Shell Method and I got stuck on this volumen question:

Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region
bounded by $y=x-x^2$ and $y=0 $ about the line y=2.

So I managed to set up the washer method as:
$\pi \displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}(2^2)-(2-(x-x^2))^2dx$ 
and the shell method as follows:
$2\pi \displaystyle \int_{0}^{1/4}(2-y)(1/2-\sqrt{y+1/4})dy$ but both give me different answers. I got stumped and couldn't figure it out, what exactly went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the shell method, solving $y=x-x^2$ for $x$ gives $x = \frac{1}{2}(1\pm\sqrt{1-4y}\,)$, so that for a given value of $y$, the height of the shell is
$$\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{1-4y}\,)-\frac{1}{2}(1-\sqrt{1-4y}\,) = \sqrt{1-4y}.$$ Thus the integral should be
$$2\pi\int_0^{1/4} (2-y)\sqrt{1-4y}\,dy,$$
which gives the same answer as you got using the washer method.

Comment: Thank you Rogerl I greatly appreciate it!